# Why does Kotlin byte code reference java.util.function.BiConsumer?

Tags: java, compilation, kotlin, java-6

From what I understand Kotlin should be able to run using JRE 6.  But this code with a `foreach` on a map fails because of a reference to a Java 8 class (`java/util/function/BiConsumer`)

CompilerTest.kt:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val aMap = mapOf("bar" to "bat")
  aMap.forEach { k, v -> println("$k -> $v")}
}
```

Compile the Kotlin code:

```
» kotlinc CompilerTest.kt -jvm-target 1.6 -include-runtime -d compilerTest.jar
```

Testing the compiled code on JRE 6:

```
» docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp openjdk:6-jdk-slim java -jar compilerTest.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/function/BiConsumer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at CompilerTestKt.main(CompilerTest.kt:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.function.BiConsumer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 12 more
```

Version Information:

```
» kotlinc -version         
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.1.4-3 (JRE 1.8.0_131-b11)
```

Answer (score 22):

Turns out that kotlin Map inherits from java.util.Map. When you call `aMap.forEach { k, v -> println("$k -> $v")}`, you are calling the [Java version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) of the method.

However, if you change the code to take an entry: `aMap.forEach { entry -> println("$entry.key -> $entry.value")}`, you are calling the [Kotlin version](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) and the code will run on JRE6.

You can flag the dependency on the JRE by compiling with the `-no-jdk` flag to the compiler.

```
» kotlinc CompilerTest.kt -no-jdk -jvm-target 1.6 -include-runtime -d compilerTest.jar
CompilerTest.kt:5:10: error: type inference failed: inline fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> Unit): Unit
cannot be applied to
receiver: Map<String, String>  arguments: ((Map.Entry<String, String>, ???) -> Unit)

    aMap.forEach { k, v -> println("$k -> $v")}
         ^
...
```

Comment: Alternatively use `aMap.forEach { (k, v) -> println("$k -> $v")}` - notice the `(k, v)`. It does `Entry` decomposition in-place

Answer (score 5):

Try to disable the Instant run, under

`Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment`

[image: Android Studio Preferences]

It was the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time

Comment: Yeah, it took me a lot of time too!

Answer (score 4):

> kotlinc-jvm 1.1.4-3 (JRE 1.8.0_131-b11)

It seems like you are using JDK 8 version. If you are using gradle, you should check your `build.gradle`.

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib" // JDK 6
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7" // JDK 7
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8" // JDK 8
```