# Android Compiling Error - Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/Function

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

After updating Gradle version to 3.1, the error below is thrown on running the application:

> **Failed to find byte code for java/util/function/Function**
>
> java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for
>   java/util/function/Function   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.lambda$static$0(AsmUtils.java:89)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:307)

May anybody help me to fix this?

The full stack error:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForMockDebug'.    at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for
>   java/util/function/Function   at
>   com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>     ... 32 more Caused by:
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for
>   java/util/function/Function   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:312)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transform(InstantRunTransform.java:178)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>     ... 48 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte
>   code for java/util/function/Function  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)    at
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:307)
>     ... 52 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for
>   java/util/function/Function   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to find byte code for
>   java/util/function/Function   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.lambda$static$0(AsmUtils.java:89)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:307)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readInterfaceHierarchy(AsmUtils.java:216)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readInterfaces(AsmUtils.java:251)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readInterfaceHierarchy(AsmUtils.java:220)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.readInterfaces(AsmUtils.java:251)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.AsmUtils.loadClass(AsmUtils.java:288)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.IncrementalVisitor.instrumentClass(IncrementalVisitor.java:342)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transformToClasses2Format(InstantRunTransform.java:406)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$doTransform$3(InstantRunTransform.java:268)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.lambda$null$4(InstantRunTransform.java:297)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>     ... 4 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a compiler issue.
Did you try restarting your Android studio?
If yes, then try

```
Build-> Clean Project
Build-> Make Project
```

If the issue still persists, try to clear cache by `File > Invalidate Caches & Restart...`

If everything fails, try disabling **Instant Run**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Cleaning the project solved the problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The only thing that fixed it was to disable instant run and try again :/.

Answer (score 29):

It seems that there are several reasons causing this problem.

If you use Kotlin, try changing `forEach{ key, value -> ... }` to `forEach{ (key, value) -> ... }`

In my situation, I never use Kotlin. After disable Instant Run, this error gone.

Comment: It worked for me as well, here is how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999705/1195507

Comment: Adding the parentheses fixed my issue, disable Instant Run is not the best solution

Answer (score 19):

I found the solution for my problem here: [Why does Kotlin byte code reference java.util.function.BiConsumer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396751/why-does-kotlin-byte-code-reference-java-util-function-biconsumer)

I am using Kotlin and I found the line that uses forEach{ key, value -> ... }, and changed it to forEach{ (key, value) -> ... }, which makes Kotlin choose JRE 6 instead of 8.

Comment: +1: Adding the parentheses fixed my issue. I was having the same issue (can't find byte code for BiConsumer) building for Android API 21, and anything API <21 was building but would crash with a ClassDefNotFoundError when it tried to run the forEach.

Comment: Adding the parentheses fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean & rebuild/make your project. If the issue still exist, [disable Instant Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off) in your android studio and run your app again, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what worked for me was to clean Android Studio preferences:

Remove .AndroidStudioX.X

Remove .gradle

Restart Android Studio

And then I ran into another issue which solution was to disable Instant Run.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

It happens when some gradle plugin doesn't match with minsdk. I was using sceneform sdk, my minsdk was 22 but it required 24. When I changed the minsdk from 22 to 24 - it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it seemed to have started all of the sudden. Disabling instant run was the only fix that worked for me. I know it was mentioned in here but didn't see any instructions on were to disable it so here you go....
In Android Studio, Select File, Settings, Build "Execution, Deployment, Instant Run", Set "Enable instant Run to Hot Swap Code/resource changes on deploy" to unchecked. Hit Apply, OK, Debug should work again. Thanks to the guys who mentioned it!